# OOP email class

Tags: php, oop, class, email

Any ideea how i can turn a basic email php sender into an fully operational oop class with functions?
And how can I call specific methods in the class to the form which has the file?

For example I have a contact.php where I have my email form and another file email.class.php where I have all oop

How can they be combined?

Comment: Do you know http://phpmailer.worxware.com/ ?

Comment: "And who can I call specific methods in the class to the form which has the file?" I can't make sense of this. At all.

Comment: I know that form a external php class you can call that class in your contact.php throut an object like this $mail =new mail(); and then you call a method form that class with $email->methodformmailclass();

Answer (score 2):

You may consider using a library like [swift mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)

Comment: Thank you but I want to create my own class with functions with very high security.

Comment: what do you mean by very high security?

Comment: Judging by this question, I guarantee you will have higher security by using a pre-existing class. You do not seem to be sufficiently experienced to reinvent the wheel.